# How can I configure Spacemacs to always add a newline at the end of files when saving?

Tags: spacemacs

I would like text files that I edit in Spacemacs to always end with a newline (`\n`) when I save them, even if I don't explicitly add it. How can I configure Spacemacs to do this?

I noticed this issue when created a file called `.clangd` with the contents

```
CompileFlags:
  Add: [-Isrc, -Isrc/effect]
```

When I wrote this file with `:w`, it did not have a newline at the end of the file.

Comment: I'm certain this question has been answered somewhere, but Google and SO search both failed me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(setq require-final-newline t)`